# How to bind a control of a row detail to the property of the view model

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, silverlight

During my development works, I want to create a datagrid with row detail information. Each row is compose with a class information such as, class name and the total number of students. When user click one row will display the all the student information of the selected class into the row detail.

The row detail control is also make up with a datagrid, each row of this grid is a student information.

The student name could be edit with an AutoCompleteBox control. The ItemSource of it should be bound to the property StudentNames of the ViewModel and not the Property of the ClassInformation. The ClassInforamtion is also a property of the ViewModel. But the result is not works. during the editing, the StudentNames is not binded currectly.

```
<UserControl ...>
   <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" ...>
        <sdk:DataGrid 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ClassInformation}"  
                  RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedClass, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  x:Name="dataGrid">
            <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Total Student" Binding="{Binding TotalStudent}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            <sdk:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding StudentInformation}">
                            <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Student Name">
                                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock x:Name="studentName" Text="{Binding SSDTestScript.Name}"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <sdk:AutoCompleteBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.StudentNames, ElementName="LayoutRoot"}" ItemFilter="{Binding ElementName=studentName, Path=Text}"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                        </sdk:DataGrid>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        </sdk:DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I have also tried or binding expressions too.

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ScriptNames}" DataContext="{Binding}" 
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ScriptNames, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Grid}}"
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ScriptNames, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"
```

By the way, how to specify the AncestorLevel in Silverlight 5? I have try this expression, but it will throw exception when i navigate to the page. Is it depend on the logic tree of xaml?

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ScriptNames, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=2}}"
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: So `StudentNames` is a property on your UserControl's view model? You could give a name to the UserControl, say `MyUserControl`, and set up the binding as follows: `ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MyUserControl, Path=DataContext.StudentNames.... />`

Comment: @Jerrington Yes StudentNames is one of the property of the view model. The datagrid is also bind to a property of the view model. So your suggestion is not works, I have tried it. Thank you all the same.

Comment: Are there any binding errors in your Output window?

Comment: @Jerrington, there is no exception of binding expression printed from the output window.